# How to display a list of divs in two columns without extra vertical space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

With below snippet, there appears extra spaces on left side between divs.
Is it possible to create two columns without altering the HTML schema? Each `child` can have dynamic content hence dynamic vertical space.I am trying to fiddle with different CSS combinations for `parent` and child.

```css
.parent{

}

.child{
  display:flex;
  float:left;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: gray;
}


/** Ignore below */
.child1{
  background-color: green;
}
.child2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.child3{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.child4{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.child5{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.child6{
  background-color: #989898;
}
.child7{
  background-color: #545454;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">Child 1 text here Child 1 text here Child 1 text here Child 1 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child3">Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child4">Child 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child5">Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child6">Child 6  text here Child 6  text here Child 6  text here Child 6  text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child7">Child 7  text here 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Floats are an outdated layout technique to begin with, but they certainly shouldn't be used in conjunction with flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more possible way would be to use `display: inline-block;`.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  column-count: 2;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child {  
  padding:10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;  
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

child1{
  background-color: green;
}
.child2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.child3{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.child4{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.child5{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.child6{
  background-color: #989898;
}
.child7{
  background-color: #545454;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">Child 1 text here Child 1 text here Child 1 text here Child 1 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child3">Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child4">Child 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child5">Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child6">Child 6  text here Child 6  text here Child 6  text here Child 6  text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child7">Child 7  text here 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: wrap` and remove `float: left`

it will take the full width of the page until there is no more space and it will wrap to a new line

in your case since you have a width of 48% it will make 2 columns with 4% left

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a full-on 'masonry' sort of layout with pure CSS as yet, but you can get two columns where the spare space - if any - will be only at the end.

Remove flex and width settings and use columns property.

```css
.parent{
  columns: 2;
}

.child{
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: gray;
}


/** Ignore below */
.child1{
  background-color: green;
}
.child2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.child3{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.child4{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.child5{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.child6{
  background-color: #989898;
}
.child7{
  background-color: #545454;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">Child 1 text here Child 1 text here Child 1 text here Child 1 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here Child 2 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child3">Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here Child 3 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child4">Child 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text hereChild 4 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child5">Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here Child 5  text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child6">Child 6  text here Child 6  text here Child 6  text here Child 6  text here 
  </div>
  <div class="child child7">Child 7  text here 
  </div>
</div>
```